# How can $\lambda$ in Poisson distribution be constant if derived from binomial distribution for $\lambda=np$ while $n$ goes to infinity?

Tags: probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

[image: Poisson from Binomial Derivation]

**My Problem.** Above is the derivation for Poisson from binomial which I quoted from somewhere. I understand this derivation mostly, but my struggle is that I do not understand why we can say $\lambda=np$, and $\lambda$ is constant in Poisson distribution.

---

**My trial.** My thought is that in a binomial distribution the probability of a success (i.e. for a certain event to happen) for each trial is constant, so $p$ is constant. Then deriving Poisson from binomial, we let $n$ approach infinity, and should not $\lambda$ go to infinity as a result as $\lambda=np$?

---

**My comment.** Any kind of idea or help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting confused because the proof is missing a few prior details. Also, it abuses notation by making you think only a single binomial distribution is involved above. This is not the case. Here is a more accurate rendition of what the proof is showing:

Fix $\lambda > 0$. And suppose $X_n \sim Binomial(n, p_n)$ is a sequence of binomial variables such that:

- each has a **different** success probability $p_n$, and
- they satisfy the very special condition $np_n = \lambda$ for all large enough $n$.

Then, the proof shows $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} P(X_n = k) = P(X = k)$ where $X \sim Poisson(\lambda)$.

So the proof isn't really deriving the Poisson distribution from the Binomial distribution. That is, the proof isn't showing Poisson is some special case of the Binomial.

Rather, it is saying that a very special collection of binomial variables, satisfying a very special condition $np_n = \lambda$, starts behaving more and more like the Poisson distribution for large $n$.

Comment: This is indeed thorough especially for your last two paragraphs. Thank you so so much!

Comment: @IncredibleSimon Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Implicitly we assume at the very beginning that $\lambda$ is a constant. $p$ *decreases* as $n\to\infty$ so as to keep the product $\lambda=np$ constant (otherwise the expression for $P(X=k)$ would not remain a valid probability).

Comment: But if Poisson is from binomial, isn't $p$ constant as required for binomial?

Comment: @IncredibleSimon We are not fixing $p$. We are fixing $np$. $p$ and $\lambda$ are two entirely different things, just as the binomial and Poisson distributions are worlds apart.

Comment: Right. Then how is it legitimate to derive Poisson from binomial if we are not following a requirement of binomial? I am confused. Thanks. @Parcly Taxel

Comment: @IncredibleSimon We can fix relations between $n$ and $p$ however we want, and the Poisson is a _limiting case_ of the binomial.

Answer (score 0):

When $\lambda$ is called a "constant" in this context, that means that among the probabilities $\dfrac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!},$ the number $\lambda$ remains the same as $k$ varies within the set $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}.$

But also, within this proof, $\lambda=np$ does not change as $n$ and $p$ change. As $n$ gets bigger, $p = \lambda/n$ gets smaller and $\lambda$ remains the same.